# Install repository in package.json: only partial repository is downloaded

Tags: git, npm

I'm trying to install a private repository as a package.json in my application with the help of this guide: [ref](http://nadafancy.com/2016/05/10/Using-private-git-repos-as-NPM-modules.html).

So I execute this command:

```
npm install -s git+ssh://server:port/repo.git
```

And I can see that the repository is added to my package.json file. The problem is that some file are missing:

```
my-library/
├── PREVIEW
├── README.md
├── build 
├── config
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── assets
│   ├── assets.js
│   ├── componentPropertyBuilder.js
│   ├── components
...
```

Same repository in node_modules:

```
components
├── PREVIEW
├── README.md
├── build
├── config
├── index.html
├── package.json
├── src
│   ├── App.vue
│   ├── assets
│   ├── components
...
```

I'm missing assets.js, componentPropertyBuilder.js, the entire Core folder with my core components...

Can someone explain to me why is that?

Comment: Are you 100% sure that all these files are in `HEAD`? Check it using `git ls-tree HEAD src/`

Comment: You were right, I didn't imported the correct branch! But in case I updated the repository with other components, how can I update the modules in node_modules? Running npm install does not updated it...

Comment: `npm update` IIRC